# Rails file_field_tag with multiple files delivers random string to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I am building a form to accept multiple images. Here's the form in Slim

```
  = form_tag(product_images_path(product_id: product.id), multipart: true, remote: true) do
    label Add Image
    = file_field_tag(:attachment, multiple: true, name: 'image[attachment]', direct_upload: true, class: 'drop-target')
    = submit_tag 'Upload'
```

When I test this form and attach a file and the data hits the controller, the attachment turns into some kind of random string instead of an array of `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` as I would expect. Here's the result of checking `params` in console:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {
  "utf8"=>"✓",
  "authenticity_token"=>"....", 
  "image"=>{"attachment"=>"eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBOQT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--79ca56f5342586a657d079d36e45f769dacc9356"},
  "commit"=>"Upload", 
  "controller"=>"rics_channels/admin/images", 
  "action"=>"create", 
  "product_id"=>"5355"} 
permitted: false>
```

I can't figure out how to properly format/process the `image[attachment]`'s.  See anything I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered that the problem was that my `file_field_tag` needed an extra `[]` in the name.

```
= file_field_tag('attachment[images][]', multiple: true, class: 'drop-target')
```

Then in the controller:

```
params[:attachment][:images]
#=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007f8a70185a90
  @content_type="image/jpeg",
  @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"attachment[images][]\"; filename=\"image1.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
  @original_filename="image.jpg",
  @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/p6/dshxxfqj6lq83t652t6j59ym0000gn/T/RackMultipart20180703-9499-9rs1km.jpg>>,
 #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007f8a70a0bac0
  @content_type="image/jpeg",
  @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"attachment[images][]\"; filename=\"image2.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
  @original_filename="image2.jpg",
  @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/p6/dshxxfqj6lq83t652t6j59ym0000gn/T/RackMultipart20180703-9499-wfuqs.jpg>>,
 #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007f8a6dc82338
  @content_type="image/jpeg",
  @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"attachment[images][]\"; filename=\"image3.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
  @original_filename="image.jpg",
  @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/p6/dshxxfqj6lq83t652t6j59ym0000gn/T/RackMultipart20180703-9499-9oe8y4.jpg>>]
```

Comment: Did you find that anywhere in the documentation? Because I'm searching for that like for days... but that didn't came to my mind. Your solution works. Thank you for answering it yourself...

Comment: Solved this a while ago... I think I may have figured it out by looking at the tests inside of the Rails source code.

Answer (score 1):

You’re using direct uploads (note that `direct_upload: true` is passed to `file_field_tag`). When the form is submitted, Active Storage’s JavaScript uploads the file directly to your storage service, bypassing your app. In lieu of the actual file, the app receives a signed blob ID.

You can pass this signed blob ID to `attach` (here I assume `file` is the name of your attachment):

```
image.file.attach(params[:image][:attachment])
```

…or use it to instantiate a new record:

```
image = Image.new(file: params[:image][:attachment])
```

Active Storage uses the signed blob ID to look up the corresponding blob and attach it to your record.