# Send / Receive javascript FileList to rails 7 controller (Drag and Drop mode)

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-7

I have a form.

```html
<form id="add_content" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/contents/create" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="*****" autocomplete="off" />
    <input type="hidden" value="*****" id="database_id" name="database_id">
    <div id="drop-area">
        <input type="file" id="file_list" name="file_list" multiple>
    </div>
</form>
```

I have some javascript to add drop event and handle all.

```js
let dropArea = document.getElementById('drop-area')

dropArea.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false)

function handleDrop(e) {
    let dt    = e.dataTransfer
    let files = dt.files

    handleFiles(files)
}

function handleFiles(files) {

    let form = document.getElementById('add_content')
    console.log(files)
    let file_list = document.getElementById('file_list')
    console.log(file_list.files.length)
    form.submit();
}
```

I drag and drop some (two) files I can see a *FileList* into console.

```js
FileList {0: File, 1: File, length: 2}
  0: File {name: 'kk.wav', lastModified: 1671550812159, lastModifiedDate: Tue Dec 20 2022 16:40:12 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 832216, …}
  1: File {name: 'kk.marcos.wav', lastModified: 1671550812023, lastModifiedDate: Tue Dec 20 2022 16:40:12 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 1147470, …}
  length: 2
  [[Prototype]]: FileList
```

But *console.log(file_list.files.length)* write *'0'* on console

After submit the form, the Payload look like this.

```
authenticity_token: *****
database_id: *****
file_list: (binary)
```

But in my controller file_list is nil

```rb
  def create
    database_id = params[:database_id]
    file_list   = params[:file_list]

    puts "================================================================="
    puts file_list.class
    puts "================================================================="
```

```
App 1686102 output: =================================================================
App 1686102 output: NilClass
App 1686102 output: =================================================================
```

Then, I add some code to my javascript function *handleFiles* to add the *FileList* to my input type file

```js
function handleFiles(files) {

    let form = document.getElementById('add_content')
    console.log(files)
    let file_list = document.getElementById('file_list')
    // Add FileList to the input type file
    file_list.files = files
    console.log(file_list.files.length)
    form.submit();
}
```

Now *console.log(file_list.files.length)* write *'2'* (this is fine) and now the controller receive a file, but just one file (the last one). Not two.

```
App 1686102 output: =================================================================
App 1686102 output: ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile
App 1686102 output: =================================================================
```

If I try to get *files_list.length* in the controller I get

```
undefined method `length' for #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007f356c0dd1c8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile: (closed)>, @content_type="audio/wav", @original_filename="kk.marcos.wav", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file_list\"; filename=\"kk.marcos.wav\"\r\nContent-Type: audio/wav\r\n">
```

What would be the proper way to send o receive more than one files?

Answer (score 0):

Well, is as easy as change the name of the input file.

```html
<input type="file" id="file_list[]" name="file_list[]" multiple>
```

instead of

```html
<input type="file" id="file_list" name="file_list" multiple>
```

Thanks to [Rails: Multiple Fileupload is missing all files but one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75336716/rails-multiple-fileupload-is-missing-all-files-but-one?rq=2)

Maybe mine is duplicated.